# For loops with itertools to count rows

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, nested, python-itertools

I have a .csv document with 16 rows. Each row starts with letters, in this case with `a` or `b`.

The outer for loop will check, line by line, the first letter. If row `x` starts with `b`, the second for-loop will count all rows until `b` occurs again.

Example:

```
1. a
2. a
3. a
4. a
5. b
6. a
7. a
8. a
9. a
10.a
11.a
12.a
13.b
14.a
…
```

`b` is found in line 5, next in row 13. There are 7 rows between…

That's my script to count rows from line 5 to line 13:

"Verschachtelteitertools"

```
import itertools
import re  
df = open('zeilen.csv')

for i, line in enumerate(df):
    #print(i,line)
    if re.search('b',line):
        #print(i,line)
        k = i+1
        count = 1
        #print(k)
        for line in itertools.islice(df,k):

            if bool(re.search('b',line)) == False:
                count=count+1
        lineX = count

print(lineX)
```

I have chosen `itertools.islice()` to count rows between `b` (1st occurrence) and `b` in line 13.
`k` should represent the starting Point of the inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

`import itertools
import re

df = open('zeilen.csv') 
for i, line in enumerate(df):
    #print(i,line)
    if re.search('b',line):
        #print(i,line)
        k = i+1
        count = 1
        #print(k)
        for line in itertools.islice(df,k):

            if bool(re.search('b',line)) == False:
                count=count+1
        lineX = count
print(lineX)`